# What is TFS alternative for JIRA "fix version"

Tags: tfs, jira, bug-tracking

Starting a work on project where they already use TFS, and I`m trying to make some changes in the process.

I` m used to JIRA and "fix version" field which I made mandatory field in transition from "TESTED" -> "DONE" on my previous project and all made super-sense.

I didn´t find something like that in TFS (I´m usinig it only for one day) and would like to know if anyone can help me if this?
I know that issues stay in iteration which was solved in... Should I let go and use iterations for this?

Kind regards,
Nejc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After go through the [Version](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/jira-agile-user-s-guide/planning-a-version) concept in JIRA.

> You can use the JQL fixVersion  field to search for a version's
>   issues.

The corresponding things in TFS are [sprint / iteration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scrum/sprint-planning).

In work item filed area, there is also a filed called **Iteration Path** .

Iteration paths allow you to group work into sprints, milestones, or other event-specific or time-related period.   Iteration path is also **hierarchical** you can create nodes that represent Releases or Milestones.

If this not 100% meet your requirement, you could simply add **a custom field** for the data that you want to track. How to do this in TFS, please refer: [Add or modify a field to track work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/add-modify-field)